# How to obtain msn contact list?

Tags: msn

Given the account and password, how to obtain the contact list of that account in msn? Are there any msn api can do this? Or I have to use the account and password to login and obtain the contact list.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a particular programming language that you wish to use?

There appears to be a [PHP Class](http://torrentialwebdev.com/blog/archives/17-Grabbing-an-MSN-contact-list.html). You could also use something like [libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple) to connect to the MSN network and download the list.

Answer (score 1):

Officially the msn protocol isn't specified. But some people have been reverse enginering the [protocol](http://www.hypothetic.org/docs/msn/).

It's not an easy protocol, as you have to connect to several server before you have everything you need.

Note however that when microsoft changes the protocol again and drops old versions, you have to wait before the new protocol version is deciphered.